# Enable custom database table fields in Wordpress Elementor

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, elementor

I have an addition database table that was created manually not generated via Wordpress. I want to integrate this table into Wordpress so I can use within the dynamic fields options in Elementor.

Please can you advise the best way to to this?

I have found a plugin called metabox.io , but not sure how to do it via that either. I can see options to create custom tables via meta box, but not integrate manually tables.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not write an import script to turn your items in the custom table into a resource that Wordpress can use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any examples of how I can do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about your custom database table, but you could just iterate over the rows and for each item, use [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) with your preferred post type. That way you could map the custom table into WP's ecosystem. But this is just a rough guess, because your question doesn't provide any details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way i can think of is to create a custom wordpress shortcode.
in the end you should have something like `[custom_table id="1" column="db_column" condition=""]`, you will be able to use this shortcode in elementor dynamic fields.

i do not know about the plugin you mentioned. if you're not familiar with wordpress development you should hire a developer to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I create a custom post type from this custom database table?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have decided to create a function / shortcode